# Como cambiar el tamaño del icono ic_launcher en NavegationView Menu

Tags: android

Necesito cambiar el  el tamaño del icono ic_launcher en NavegationView, alguien me pude decir como hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No, yo necesito cambiar el tamaño del icono app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"

Comment: Como sabes ques ic_launcher_round  es el que carga en la imagen que muestras?

Answer (score 1):

Debes modificar los valores de los atributos **android:layout_width** y **android:layout_height** que estan como **wrap_content**

```xml
<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Por tamaños específicos, ejemplo:

```xml
<ImageView
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

en tu nav_header de tu drawer, cambia los valores layout_width y layout_height.
Ejemplo:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
```